# Sails js bulk upload and insert into MongoDB

Tags: mongodb, sails.js, waterline

Hi In my Sailsjs application there is bulk upload feature where a admin can upload csv file. I am using csv-parse for parsing the csv content.

Now i want to insert the data into Mongo DB where each row has Vehicle Info and Test Info. These two models have one to many relationship. I am not able to figure out how to insert them into DB. Below is my code for inserting the vehicle.

Below is the code sample i was thinking to create VehicleTest model once Vehicle model is created but i don't have access to vehicle to get info for vechileTest model

Vehicle Model

```
attributes: {
  make: {
    type: "string",
    required: true

  },


  tests :{
    collection: 'VehicleTest',
    via : 'vehicleTested'
  },
```

VechileTest model

```
 attributes: {


vehicleTested :{
  modal :'Vehicle',
  required:true
},
```

Below lines of code from the function reads the file and parse it

```
 var parse = require('csv-parse');
var fs = require("fs")
var createdVehicle =[];
var stream = files[0].fd;

fs.readFile(stream, 'utf8', function (err, data) {
  // Print the contents of the file as a string here
  // and do whatever other string processing you want

  parse(data, {columns: true,delimiter:'|'}, function(err, output){


    if(output.length>0)
    {
      for (var i = 0, len = output.length; i < len; i++) {

        var vehicle_TestInfo  = output[i];
        //console.log(vehicle_TestInfo);
        //
        Vehicle.create({make : vehicle_TestInfo.make,model:vehicle_TestInfo.model,year:vehicle_TestInfo.year ,engineFuel:vehicle_TestInfo.engineFuel,obdZone:vehicle_TestInfo.obdZone,generation:vehicle_TestInfo.generation,protocol:vehicle_TestInfo.protocol,onStar:vehicle_TestInfo.onStar}).exec(function(err,vehCreated){

          console.log(vehCreated);
          //VehicleTest.Create({vehicleTested:vehCreated._id,overAllComp:vehicle_TestInfo.overAllComp,deviceGeneration:vehicle_TestInfo.deviceGeneration}).exec(function(err,testCreated){
          //
          //  console.log(testCreated);
          //
          //})


      });
    }
    }
```

Comment: How do you not have Vehicle info when you're inside the callback for the Vehicle create function? Apart from the spelling errors, the code seems fine. Can you clarify what you mean by not having access to Vehicle?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this is how i implemented

```
 for (var i = 0, len = output.length; i < len; i++) {

        var vehicle_TestInfo  = output[i];
        //console.log(vehicle_TestInfo);
        //
       Vehicle.create({make : vehicle_TestInfo.make,model:vehicle_TestInfo.model,year:vehicle_TestInfo.year ,trim:vehicle_TestInfo.trim ,engineFuel:vehicle_TestInfo.engineFuel,obdZone:vehicle_TestInfo.obdZone,generation:vehicle_TestInfo.generation,protocol:vehicle_TestInfo.protocol,onStar:vehicle_TestInfo.onStar,
       tests : {deviceGeneration:vehicle_TestInfo.deviceGeneration,overAllComp:vehicle_TestInfo.overAllComp,isTested:vehicle_TestInfo.isTested,testingInferred:vehicle_TestInfo.testingInferred,vinRead:vehicle_TestInfo.vinRead,
         odoRead:vehicle_TestInfo.odoRead,pidRead:vehicle_TestInfo.pidRead,doorLocked:vehicle_TestInfo.doorLocked,SeatBelt:vehicle_TestInfo.seatBelt,fuelLevel:vehicle_TestInfo.fuelLevel,issueType:vehicle_TestInfo.issueType,degreeOfERGIntr:vehicle_TestInfo.degreeOfERGIntr,dataLoggerModel:vehicle_TestInfo.dataLoggerModel,
         numberOfVehicle:vehicle_TestInfo.numberOfVehicle,remarks:vehicle_TestInfo.remarks}}).exec(function(err,vehCreated){

          if(err && err.originalError && err.originalError.code===50)
          {
              Vehicle.update({id:vehCreated.id})

          }
         /// console.log(vehCreated);
         // vehCreated.tests.add({})
          createdVehicle.push(vehCreated);



      });
```